# Im running into a problem with my while loop and getting it to restart

Tags: python

I've done a while loop with a input at the start and after 1 incorrect or correct output the loop finishes? any tips or what I'm missing, sorry to dump a large amount of code

```
playgame = True

while playgame == True:
    playgame = input("\nPlease enter choice\n [list, heroes, villains, search, reset, add, remove, battle, quit]:") 

    if playgame == "list" :
        display_characters(character_list, 0)


    elif playgame == "heroes" :
        display_characters(character_list, 1)

    elif playgame == "villains" :
        display_characters (character_list, 2)

    elif playgame == "search" :
        print(" ")
        name = input("Please enter name:")

        find_character(character_list, name)

    elif playgame == 'reset' :
        print("")
        name = input("Enter the name of the character: ")
        print ("")
        index = 0
        result = -1
        for character in character_list:
            if character == value:
                result = index
            index += 1
        if result == -1 :
            print ("")
            print (value, "is not found in character (heroes and villains) list.")
            print ("")

        else:
            character_list[result].set_health(100)
            print("")
            print ("Successfully upadted", value, "health to 100")
            print("")





    elif playgame == "add\n" :
      name = input("Enter the name of the character:")
      print("")
      secret_id = input ("Enter the secret identity of the character:")
      print("")
      hero = input ("Enter if the character is hero or villain [h/v]:")
      print ('')
      if hero == "h" :
          is_hero = True

      elif hero == "v" :
          is_hero = False

          if name in character_list:
              print(name, "already exists in the character list")
      add_character(character_list, name, secret_id, is_hero)
      print ('')

    elif playgame == "battle" :
        print("")
        do_battle(character_list, opponent1_pos, opponent2_pos)


    elif playgame == "quit" :
        print("\n\n-- Program terminating --\n")
        playgame == False

    else:
        print("\nNot a valid command - please try again.")
        playgame == True
```

Comment: You reassign “playgame" with your input statement

Comment: This appears to just be a typo. You have `playgame == False` at the bottom. That should be `playgame = False` (along with the similar instance below that). Also, why use the same variable for `input`?

Comment: ahh yeah i see i made a mistake in assigning the same variable thanks guys

Comment: Don't use a variable. Just use `while True:`, and then use a `break` statement when you want to end the loop.